# Design Issue with HD Screen in Android

Tags: android, layout, gridview

Here I develop one Android application which has Bookshelf screen. But when I tested it on HTC-Salsa and SonyXperia-Sola I found major difference and ugly looking in SonyXperia-Sola.

HTC Mobile Screen is following.

[image]

Sony Mobile Screen is following.

[image]

Here I use custom gridview to display books, I fill this gridview with BaseAdapter and I set xml layout for gidviewitem, in gridview item xml layout I fix the book size, width = 150dp and height = 170dp.

Comment: what are the differences in the screen sizes of the two phones?

Comment: For Sony 480 x 854 pixels, For HTC 320 x 480 pixels

Comment: For HTC 320 x 480 pixels

Comment: Not sure what's causing the problem but to be honest I think I like the Sony Mobile Screen book layout better, it looks much neater than the three separate books thing you have in the first image

Comment: But my PM want HTC screen display in SonyXperia. SonyXperia is HD Screen.

Comment: is your book images the same size for all resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the pixel value to dp according to density, and now it works.

Comment: @Youddh: Answering your question is perfectly valid, but please give it a little bit more love. Add a code-example and explain a little more what the actual problem was and the solution of it. That is very helpful for others then. Thank you a lot for participating on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Use embedded horizontal `LinearLayouts` instead and give each book item the same `layout_weight`.
Like.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bookshelf_row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/book_image"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/book_image"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/third_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/book_image"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>
```